# Can't boot into Phoenix BIOS, system just boots after entering password

Tags: passwords, bios, phoenix

I have a Fujitsu Siemens notebook (Model: M9400) that has the BIOS currently set to Quick Boot . I want to switch this off to be able to boot from a CD. (And I just want my BIOS access back.

The notebook is password protected to boot (as is the BIOS). When I boot the notebook, I need to hold <kbd>ESC</kbd> to be able to press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the BIOS. When I do so, the system shows `Starting up Set-up`.

However, after I type in the password, the system just boots into Windows 7 and not the BIOS. Is there anyone who know how to get into this BIOS?

**I do know the passwords** so I'm not looking for an option to remove these per se, but neither the user nor the supervisor password will get me into the BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself. All bootable media and peripheral devices had to be removed from the USB ports/DVD drives for some odd reason. Hope this information helps someone else!

Comment: Glad you had it solved, but that is really odd if you had to remove those. A friend of mine had a similar issue with a computer, whenever he restarted the computer, he had to remove all plugged usb before so. It was because of the usb ports.

Comment: @w0rldart Yes I don't have a clue why you have to remove all peripherals... Some BIOSes allow flashing through a USB drive so it might have something to do with that... Still, seems like bad programming if that is the cause.

Comment: Try upgrading your bios?

Comment: @w0rldart It's the latest version already...

Comment: lol, than maybe the usb hubs does the same thing as it did to my friend... short circuit when something was plugged in upon restart

Comment: @w0rldart Could be... Not sure if it's by design, a bug or really a hardware failure...

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_bios.htm you have a list with all (I think) the Bios Access Keys

> **Phoenix Technologies** - *Phoenix BIOS, Phoenix-Award BIOS*
>
> Press **Del** during the Power On Self Test, immediately after the computer starts.
>   Many older Phoenix BIOS systems required **Ctrl+Alt+Esc**, **Ctrl+Alt+Ins**, or **Ctrl+Alt+S** to access BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm sure I got all the keys right! The solution is the one I posted as an answer. Thanks for taking the effort though!